# Is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{f(c\frac{i}{n})}{f(c\frac{i}{n})+f(c-c\frac{i}{n})}=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, summation

So I was trying some code on Octave. The algorithm is the following

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{f(c\frac{i}{n})}{f(c\frac{i}{n})+f(c-c\frac{i}{n})}$$

for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

I noticed that for inputs $n\in \{0,...,10^5\}$, $f(x)\in\{x,\;x^2,\;\sin x,\;\cos x,\;e^x,\;\ln x\}$ and several values of $c\in\mathbb{R}$ that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{f(c\frac{i}{n})}{f(c\frac{i}{n})+f(c-c\frac{i}{n})}=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$$

Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: Change the summation variable $i\to n-i$ (i.e. summing from top to bottom instead of bottom to top) and add the two expression from the sum to get something very simple.

Comment: but will it be equal to $\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$?

Comment: It is, but the sum has to start at $n=0$ for that to be true.

Comment: Can you please post the answer? I know it might be tedious to write but I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Is $c$ a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c \frac{i}{n})}{f(c \frac{i}{n}) + f(c\frac{n-i}{n})} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{f(c \frac{n-j}{n})}{f(c\frac{n-j}{n}) + f(x_{n-j})} $$

which means that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c \frac{i}{n}) + f(c\frac{n-i}{n}) }{f(c \frac{i}{n})+ f(c\frac{n-i}{n})} = n =  2 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c \frac{i}{n})}{f(c \frac{i}{n}) + f(c\frac{n-i}{n})} $$

I believe you summed values from $i=0$ to $n$ in your code.

Comment: Note that $i = n-j+\color{red}{1}$ for the first equality to be correct, i.e. $j=1$ corresponds to $i=n$ and $j=n$ corresponds to $i=1$. If you start with $i=0$ then everything is fine though.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you Winther

Answer (score 0):

I think your sum starts at $i=0$ so you have $n+1$ terms.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{f(c\frac{i}{n})}{f(c\frac{i}{n})+f(c-c\frac{i}{n})}$$

$$= \frac{f(c\frac{0}{n})}{f(c\frac{0}{n})+f(c)} +\frac{f(c\frac{1}{n})}{f(c\frac{1}{n})+f(c\frac{n-1}{n})} + \frac{f(c\frac{2}{n})}{f(c\frac{2}{n})+f(c\frac{n-2}{n})} + \cdots \\+\frac{f(c\frac{n-2}{n})}{f(c\frac{n-2}{n})+f(c\frac{2}{n})}+\frac{f(c\frac{n-1}{n})}{f(c\frac{n-1}{n})+f(c\frac{1}{n})}+\frac{f(c)}{f(c)+f(0)}$$

which is clearly $\dfrac{n+1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd, and is also $ \dfrac{n}{2} + \dfrac{f(\frac{c}{2})}{f(\frac{c}{2})+f(\frac{c}{2})} = \dfrac{n+1}{2}$ when $n$ is even.